# Server address or IP for the servlet weather service is currently still hard-coded

Tags: java, android, web-services, servlets, sharedpreferences

Hello to all you Java and Android experts, I can really use your help with some project for my school, since I am stuck with no clue.

In the activity ServletWeatherAPI, the server address or IP for the servlet weather service is currently still hard-coded, for example:

```
Private final static String baseURL = "http://192.168.178.21:8080/WeatherService/weather? ";
```

In the Settings tab of the MultiWeatherApp, I need to add an option to specify the address or IP of my server (without the servlet path "/ WeatherService /
Weather? "). 
A web request for this weather service should use the address stored in the SharedPreferences.

Any one have an idea how can I do this? since I have none.
I know how to add to the preferences.xml the option but no idea about the rest.
I attach my project from github and the calls ServletWeatherAPI.
Any help will be much appreciated, I am no expert so a pseudocode will be very helpful to understand it.
[my app in Github](https://github.com/elivanK/MultiWeatherApp)

```
public class ServletWeatherAPI implements IWeatherAPI {
private final static String baseURL = "http://localhost:8080/WeatherService/weather?";
private JSONObject weatherdata;

private ServletWeatherAPI(String queryString) throws
        IOException, JSONException {
    String result = HttpRequest.request(baseURL + queryString);
    weatherdata = new JSONObject(result);
}

public static IWeatherAPI fromLocationName(String locationName) throws IOException, JSONException {
    return new ServletWeatherAPI("q=" + URLEncoder.encode(locationName, "UTF-8"));
}

public static IWeatherAPI fromLatLon(double lat, double
        lon) throws IOException, JSONException {
    return new ServletWeatherAPI("lat=" + lat + "&lon=" + lon);
}


@Override
public double getTemperature() throws JSONException {
    return weatherdata.getDouble("tempC");
}

@Override
public String getDescription() throws JSONException {
    return weatherdata.getString("description");
}

@Override
public String getError() {
    return "";
}

@Override
public String getProviderInfo() {
    return "ServletWeatherService";
}

@Override
public String getIconPath() throws JSONException {
    return "serlvetweatherservice/" +
            weatherdata.getString("icon");
}
```

}

Comment: `I know how to add to the preferences.xml the option `. Unclear. What do you mean? And why cant you use it?

Comment: To add an option in the settings menu (its set in preferences.xml) in a design point of it is clear to me, but how to program it is not.

Comment: It is unclear what you want to program and with what you have problems.

Comment: I will make it more clear:

Comment: So you have difficulties to change the baseUrl? You can do that in the constructor by just adding a baseUrl parameter. Change `private ServletWeatherAPI(String queryString)` to `private ServletWeatherAPI(String baseUrl, String queryString)`. And in the constructor member add  'this.baseUrl = baseUrl;` After that you will see that you should declare baseUrl different from `Private final static String baseURL`.

Comment: I created another option EditTextPreferneces in my preferences.xml with the key="server_address". When I put value in the edittext it will be stored in my main class under a string that I retrieve from the sharedPreferences String serverAddress = Prefs.getString("server_address", "");
Now what I need is to configure that what ever it is that I store in that String has to apply to my ServletWeatherAPI class, my question is (basic Java) how do I do that?

 private final static String ServerAddress ="";  private final static String baseURL = "http://localhost:8080/" + ServerAddress;

Comment: `String url =  "http://<ip>:8080/WeatherService/weather"; new ServletWeatherAPI ( url, querystring);` should do. Indeed basic.

Comment: I already have it in my code:

Comment: private ServletWeatherAPI(String queryString) throws IOException, JSONException {
        String result = HttpRequest.request(baseURL + queryString);
        weatherdata = new JSONObject(result);
    }

Comment: You missed my comment with explanation.

Comment: Obviously you missed my suggestion to give it an extra parameter.

Comment: I have a String value that is declared in one Activity and I want to retrieve it in another activity and set it to a static String.
How can it be done?

Comment: You did not comment on that extra parameter.

Comment: Your suggestion cannot be applied with the code.

Comment: Of course it can. And if you think it can not you should explain why you think so.

Comment: In the public static IWeatherAPI fromLocationName and fromLatLon I get the following error: ServletWeatherAPI (String, String) in ServletWeatherAPI cannot be applied to (String).

Comment: Indeed. If you do not do it in the right way you get such compile time errors. Not a reason to say that the suggestion cannot be applied. It is just a basic adaption you have to make.

Comment: Okay that sounds very nice. What is the right way? The only thing that I still don't understand is how to change the API base url? I am very bad with theoretical stuff and much more good with pseudocode.

Comment: I have shown and told you exactly what you have to do.

Comment: "Very good explanation and very helpful", thx!

Answer (score 0):

I have found the solution if anyone will be interested, here's my git:
[MultiWeatherApp](https://github.com/elivanK/MultiWeatherApp)